# Overview of branch relationships in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a repo with a long history and various long-running named branches, some closed and some still open. I would like to know which branches depend on which, so that I can tell, for example, if branch A is effectively a twig or if other branches depend on it. Is there a way to see a high-level overview, or simplified diagrams, of the relationships between branches?

```
                       y-y-y-y-y
                      /
...o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-
      \         /           
       x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x
```

For example, in the above I cannot drop the entire `x` branch, since the default `o` depends on part of it. But scrolling down hundreds of entries in the output of `hg log --graph`, I might not notice the merge.

Basically I'm looking for a record of splits and merges, as if long sequences of commits in the same branch were collapsed into a single commit. (Of course it would be useful to know *which* ranges were collapsed.) Alternately, a very compact graphic representation might make an overview possible in some other way, or there might be a non-visual (textual) way to summarize the dependencies.

```
                  y--y
                 /
...o--o ---- o--o--o
       \    /
        x--x
```

I use both commandline `hg` and `tortoise HG`, so I'm happy with solutions based on either one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TortoiseHg, you can enable a filter and use:

```
head() or merge() or parents(merge())
```

This should only show heads, merges and parents of merges so you can see how everything interrelates.

Another useful one is `not follow()`.  If updated to the tip of `o` above, it would show the stubs of `x` and `y` that aren't merged into `o`.

Comment: @torek If you like ASCII tree graphs... :^)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! I hadn't used the filter feature before, but with your filter plus the exclusion of some branches ( `... and not (branch(A) or branch(B))`), I can prune things down enough to make it reviewable.